# Laravel 5: Can't get model property in relationship

Tags: properties, laravel-5, where-clause, relationship, has-many

I have a relationship in my model that requires a where condition:

> ```
> public function characters() {
>     return $this->hasMany('Character')->where('characters.game_id', $this->game_id);
> }
> ```

The problem is that "$this->game_id" doesn't appear to work. If I hard code the ID I need in its place, then the relationship works fine. I've also tried "$this->attributes['game_id']", which doesn't work either. I know that the value for "$this->game_id" exists, because I can view it when I return it in an accessor or as just a normal property in the resulting object. But for whatever reason, I can't access this value in the relationship. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you require that particular where clause? I think `hasMany` does that for you.

Comment: That would be the case if this relationship were part of the "game" model, though it's actually another model, so it is necessary to get the exact relationship I need.

Comment: Ok. So could you please provide more details?